# Convert String Date to Date data type

Tags: r

Month_Yr
2007-01
2008-03
2009-04

I want to convert these into a date data type. i used the as.Date function but it keeps printing out NA.

```
total_data$Month_Yr2 = as.Date(as.yearmon(total_data$Month_Yr), "%m-%Y")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a day to have the date, so you can add:

```
#Data
string <- '2007-01'
#Format
new <- as.Date(paste0(string,'-01'),'%Y-%m-%d')
```

And after that you can use `format()`:

```
#Format 2
new2 <- format(new,"%m-%Y")
```

Ending up with:

```
[1] "01-2007"
```